# Setting the same timezone everywhere in CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using CloudWatch and I find that timezones appear in either UTC or the local timezone variously in different contexts. For example, when I look at one right now, in CloudWatch > Logs I see Log Streams shown in local time. In Metrics, they appear in UTC.

This can make troubleshooting difficult.

How can I ensure that a single timezone appears in all contexts, all throughout CloudWatch?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This answer follows the layout of the CloudWatch console (at the time of writing).

The procedure should fix the time zone in all contexts other than Event Rule Schedule Expressions, where Amazon's documentation states that only UTC is possible.

**PROCEDURE**

Go to CloudWatch console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/

**Metrics**

In the nagivation pane, choose **Metrics**.

Choose the custom menu and then choose **UTC** or **Local timezone**.

This will take effect in all contexts where metrics are displayed, e.g. in **Dashboards**, **Lambda** functions etc.

**Logs**

In the navigation pane, choose **Logs**.

For **Log Groups**, choose any log group to view some streams.

For **Log Streams**, choose any log stream name to view some log data.

Now to change the timezone, click on the blue date/time in the top-right corner. Choose **UTC** or **Local timezone** and then click **Cancel**.

**Alarms history**

Under **Alarms**, there are alarms, and on selecting an alarm, there is a **History** tab. These take their timezone from the Metrics above. There should be nothing to do in here.

**Events**

Under **Events** there are **Schedule expressions for Rules**. Unfortunately, as noted above, Amazon's documentation states that all scheduled events use UTC time zone.

**References**

[Modify the Time Range or Time Zone Format for a Graph](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/modify_graph_date_time.html)

[Working With Log Groups and Log Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Working-with-log-groups-and-streams.html)

[Schedule Expressions for Rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html)

Comment: Where should I set the local timezone?

Comment: Your local timezone should be coming from your browser i think. "Local time is the time zone that's specified in your computer's operating system. " - ref https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/change_dashboard_time_format.html

Answer (score 7):

## Lambda function - 'Monitoring' ['CloudWatch metrics at a glance']

(apparently not controlled in CloudWatch console)

*'custom' menu/dropdown > 'Local timezone':*

[image]

Comment: I seem to recall that the instructions I documented below did fix the timezone in this Lambda context. Just checking, did you firstly follow all the below instructions?

Comment: I only followed directions you gave for Metrics, since the CloudWatch metrics in Lambdas is all I am presently focused on.  I don't see how the other sections would relate (i.e: there are no logs in those CloudWatch metrics).  Your Answer is a good main reference.

Comment: Thank you for the screenshot. Sooo much clearer than explaining in text <3