# Amazon CloudWatch Logs: How to set time zone format in a consistent way, preferably in one palce?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, timezone-offset

There are number of useful SOF threads on how to set preferred time format for CloudWatch components, such as log insights or dashboards: [Setting the same timezone everywhere in CloudWatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51887396/setting-the-same-timezone-everywhere-in-cloudwatch) or [AWS Log insights: specify @timestamp field output format/timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62669258/aws-log-insights-specify-timestamp-field-output-format-timezone).

Following these, I was able to set the required time in my preferred format like `2023-06-07T12:13:10.869Z`.

But here's I see a problem: there seem to be no consistency between how timezones are selected in different parts of CloudWatch.

So, `Log insights` and `Dashboards` have individual timezone selectors under the "Custom" control.

That could be confusing as one needs to remember to switch these individualy. On the other hand, I can foresee how one (me as an example) would want to have consistent time zone format set across all components of CloudWatch/AWS.

Is that done on puprose - or is there a global setting somewhere allowing to set preferred format for time for all components within AWS or at least CloudWatch?